# Are all first-order truths of real arithmetic also true of the algebraic reals?

Tags: model-theory, first-order-logic, real-numbers

Consider sentences in first-order logic which are true of the structure $(\mathbb R, +, \cdot, <, 0, 1)$, where the symbols have their usual meaning. Is every such sentence also true of $(\mathbb A, +, \cdot, <, 0, 1)$, where $\mathbb A$ is the set of algebraic real numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

The reason is that the two fields are models of the complete theory of **Real-Closed Fields**. One of the characterization of real-closed fields is that their algebraic closure is an extension of degree $2$, which is clearly true for both fields.